Program 'python.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
whenever I type python from powershell  on windows 10 I get this in user mode:
Program 'python.bat' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

However it works fine if I launch the powershell in admin mode.
A week back it was fine in user mode as well. I feel some software installation in between might have messed up the permission. How do I fix the permission of python.bat file ?
I have read through similar questions on stackoverflow , titiles on most of those is same but probably none of their solution works for me.

I find it odd that it finds python.bat rather than an exe file. Usually PowerShell Get-Command python shows the full path of python.exe. I don't even have a python.bat file as far as I know

@qrsngky I install python via pyenv. So my python path is like this C:\Users\hp\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.0

You should check the above location, or the local directory, to see why it contains a python.bat script.

@OldBoy it contains python.exe and two levels up C:\Users\hp\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin has  pyenv.batboth of whose permissions seems to be fine. https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/09c85bee-d481-4dea-b47b-efdcb73a17c3

You will need to investigate the search path(s) that Powershell is using, and why it finds, or thinks it finds, a python.bat file somewhere. In my system if I type "python" at the Powershell prompt, it correctly starts.

I wonder what you get if you just run Get-Command python in Powershell. Does it tell you the location of python.bat?

@qrsngky  it says source as the same shim under pyenv ie  PS C:\Users\hp\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\python

Finally managed to reproduce the issue.
Go to C:\Users\<username>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims\  in Explorer, right click python.bat, then click Properties. Then go to the Security tab and click Edit... . Then you can modify the "Deny" parts for each user.
